# Существует ли слово "прокрещенный", если да, то что означает?

Tags: семантика

Что означает слово "прокрещенный"? Есть ли такое слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кем-то используется, значит, есть. Только вот каков его статус? В словарях его нет, значит, это не общеупотребительная лексика активного состава. Однако кое-где встречается. Вот встретилось в поэзии у одного из современных авторов:

Я думаю, это – Луна. Нет! Я – верю!..

Что это Оттуда взирают на нас

забытые людом в **прокрещенный** час,

титаны и боги, и, может, герои...

Я (шепотом можно?) их вижу порою,

и души умЕршие также летят

на встречу с Аидом, в распахнутый Ад,

и нет ничего в этом страшном – я верю,

а только – работа над мозгом за «дверью»...

Здесь **прокрещенный час** - час **прокрестили** как прострелили, пробили крестами сквозь, окончательно.

Вот ещё:

> Чтобы Провешенный = Прокрещенный Путь превратился в Поток = Дхарму,
>   ...
>   Здесь **прокрещенный путь** в значении "его прокрестили" сплошь, много раз и глубоко.

Скорее всего, это авторские неологизмы - окказионализмы, образованные по модели "приставка про-  +глагольная форма".

Посмотрим значения приставки.

> Про..., приставка. Образует глаголы со значением:
>
> 1) действия, направленного сквозь, через что-нибудь, например пробить, прострелить, протечь;
>
> 2)действия, распространяющегося во всей полноте на весь предмет,
>
> например просолить, прокрасить, прогреть;
>
> 3) движения мимо  чего-нибудь или продвижения вперёд, например проехать, пробежать, прошагать;
>
> 4) полной законченности, исчерпанности или тщательности
>   действия (возможно с постфиксом «-ся»), например пропеть,
>   пронумеровать, прогладить, провороваться, проспаться;
>
> 5) действия, осуществляемого в один приём (преимуществ. о звучании), 
>   например
>   провизжать, прорычать, прошуметь, пробарабанить;
>
> 6) действия, развивающегося во всём объёме в течение какого-нибудь промежутка
>   времени, например проработать (весь день), просидеть (всю ночь),
>   проболеть, промучиться (какое-нибудь время), проблуждать;
>
> 7) действия, обозначающего утрату, ущерб, нежелательность результата
>   (возможно с постфиксом «-ся»), например прожить (деньги), проиграть,
>   прокутить, прозевать, проболтаться, просчитаться; 8) упущения,
>   например прогулять, прокараулить, проглядеть; 9) собственно предела
>   действия, например прочитать (книгу), проговорить (сказать), пробить
>   (о бое часов).

Значения 1,2,4 могут подойти для образования глагола от **крестить**.

Comment: Вот нашлось у Даля: **Прокрещивать, _прокрестить_** что, перекрещивать, пересекать накрест. **— ся,** страдат. || Всю ночь промолился и прокрестился. https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/ТСД2/Прокрещивать

Comment: Ну да, это к 6 значению. Так что идёт активное словообразование глаголов с про-, только от этого значения прокрещенный не образуешь, только прокрестившийся.

Answer (score 0):

Такого слова не существует. Это новодел, причём вычурный.

Смысл же его легко понимаем. Если о человеке -- то этот тот, кого неоднократно осеняли крестом. Если о ткани -- то это отрез, плотно прошитый крестом
(имеетя в виду вышивание крестом как вид рукоделия).

И всё-таки мне это слово кажется вымученным. Я бы не рекомендовал вводить его в речь.